# CSS column break in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm trying to figure out a cross-browser method for implementing a columned layout for an unordered list. The markup is coming out of a CMS, so I cannot modify the output outside of adding a class(es). I can get the columns to work, but I also need to dictate the column breaks as the columns are not always equal. The markup looks like:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.c3 {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
.colBreak {
  -moz-column-break-before: always;
  -webkit-column-break-before: always;
  column-break-before: always;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class='c3'>
  <li class='colBreak'>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li class='colBreak'>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
  <li>Item6</li>
  <li>Item7</li>
  <li>Item8</li>
  <li>Item9</li>
  <li>Item10</li>
  <li class='colBreak'>Item11</li>
  <li>Item12</li>
  <li>Item13</li>
  <li>Item14</li>
</ul>
```

CSS (works well in Chrome and even in IE/Edge, but fails in Firefox):

The desired outcome here is a 3 column layout (which I do get) where Item1, Item3 and Item11 are the top elements in the 3 columns.

In Chrome, it looks swell:
[image: Chrome Output]

In Firefox, I get the bold text on Item1,Item3 & Item11
[image: Firefox Output]

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcgetv62/1/)

Comment: see: http://caniuse.com/#search=column

Comment: @GCyrillus, that does point out the issue, but I still do not have a working alternative.

Comment: there is none for firefox at this time. you'll need some tricky Javascript to insert empty containers to fill bottom of columns before the element you want to see standing at the top of next column, breaking it into many ul or not  .... :(

Comment: a flex alternative with margin-bottom instead growing some elements, eitherway an height should be fixed http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXEyqE and the column-count/fill version http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyJEgY no idea how to sort this out via js, manually is kind of easy

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working with the output, additional classes and some jQuery. Instead of indicating where the colBreaks were, I assigned each navigation item a column class

```
<ul class='c3'>
  <li class='col1'>Item1</li>
  <li class='col1'>Item2</li>
  <li class='col2'>Item3</li>
  <li class='col2'>Item4</li>
  <li class='col2'>Item5</li>
  <li class='col2'>Item6</li>
  <li class='col2'>Item7</li>
  <li class='col2'>Item8</li>
  <li class='col2'>Item9</li>
  <li class='col2'>Item10</li>
  <li class='col3'>Item11</li>
  <li class='col3'>Item12</li>
  <li class='col3'>Item13</li>
  <li class='col3'>Item14</li>
</ul>
```

Then, using the jQuery wrapAll method, I was able to add bootstrap classes to break it up into columns:

```
$(".c3 .col1").wrapAll("<div class='col-sm-4' />");
$(".c3 .col2").wrapAll("<div class='col-sm-4' />");
$(".c3 .col3").wrapAll("<div class='col-sm-4' />");
```

This grouped all of the `.col1` items into a `<div>` and got the breaks without using spacers.

[Working (in FireFox) JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcgetv62/2/)

If anyone has a better method to accomplish this, I'd love to see it. However, this is working for this particular issue.